# libgdx images go out of proportion on some devices

Tags: libgdx, resolution, aspect-ratio, mipmaps

I'm trying to develop a simple game using libgdx. The game works perfectly on emulator ( Nexus 5x API 26 x86 ). But when I generated its apk and tested on my phone(Samsung J7), the images somehow seem to go out of proportion.

I dont know if the problem is libgdx-specific or something else is causing the problem. I suspect that the issue is about the different screen sizes or resolution.

[image: This is how I want it to be.]
This is how I want it to be.

[image: This is how it appears.]
This is how it appears. The images appear to be enlarged.

The app seems to work as expected on larger mobile screens but the images do not scale well to smaller screens.

Does libGdx or the android not automatically resize images according to the hardware being run on ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit :

`boy = new Texture("boyfinal.png");
batch.draw(boy, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4 - boy.getWidth()/2, boyY  );`

Comment: You should show us the code that draws these images. It looks like it's configured to draw them at a fixed pixel size, rather than at a size that's scaled to the device resolution.

Comment: @DMGregory Can using viewports solve this problem ? [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

Comment: Sounds like you should update your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example - all of the code needed to demonstrate this problem, including whatever you've tried doing with viewports.